# REDIS - детали работы

Tags: redis

Пытаюсь разобраться в деталях работы с java spring boot redis и библиотекой
spring-boot-starter-data-redis

Работаю по примеру
https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Configure-Connection-Pooling-With-Redis-In-Spring-Boot/

Пример запустить у себя локально удалось. В плюс к нему создал restcontroller, который просто ложит в базу Redis в формате String-String некий ключ значение. Например: key1-value1.
Подключаюсь после записи значения в базе к docker контейнеру Redis выполняя комманду redis-cli, ввожу команду: info keyspace

Получаю:
db0:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0

Вопрос следующий: можно ли руками, как в sql базах, задать имя используемой базы данных, в данному случае, если я правильно понял, база данных создается автоматически и имеет имя db0, нашел информацию по вынесению параметров доступа к базе Redis в файл properties, по ссылке:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-properties
там указан следующий вариант:

spring.redis.database=0

spring.redis.host=localhost

spring.redis.port=16379

spring.redis.password=mypass

spring.redis.timeout=60000

Мне не понятно почему в redis в качестве базы данных задается индекс? Не могли бы подсказать, где можно подчерпнуть более подробную информацию по данной теме или объяснить?

Второй вопрос, если пользоваться командой redis-cli->get имя ключа, например get key1, то получаю значение для указанного ключа, если баз в Redis несколько, то будет поиск по всем ключам, всех баз? Как указать Redis текущую базу и как вывести информацию о ней найти не получается.

Comment: Вопрос не имеет отношения к spring. Так уж устроен редис, что логические базы именуются числами от 0. `redis-cli` выбор делается параметом `-n номер` или командой select в инетрактивном режиме.

Comment: Удалил из темы письма упоминание Spring, спасибо за комментарий. Roman, а где можно про эти детали более подробно?

Comment: По-русски - не знаю, по-английски тут https://redis.io/commands/select, https://redis.io/topics/rediscli и https://helpmanual.io/help/redis-cli/